# Recode character vector with some empty strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using the `dplyr::recode()` function to recode some variables.  I have one character variable with some empty strings that I would also like to recode.  But if I refer to the empty string in the arguments to the function, I get an error.

```
# input
x <- c("a", "b", "", "x", "y", "z")
# desired output
c("Apple", "Banana", "Missing", "x", "y", "z")

dplyr::recode(x, "a"="Apple", "b"="Banana", ""="Missing")

Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

If I treat the empty string as a missing value, the function leaves it as an empty string.

```
dplyr::recode(x, "a"="Apple", "b"="Banana", .missing="Missing")

[1] "Apple"  "Banana" ""       "x"      "y"      "z"
```

How can I recode the values to get the desired output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `na_if` to get `.missing` working properly:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "", "x", "y", "z")
dplyr::recode(na_if(x,""), "a"="Apple", "b"="Banana", .missing="Missing")

[1] "Apple"   "Banana"  "Missing" "x"       "y"       "z"
```

Comment: Excellent.  Was not aware of the na_if() function.  Worked right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use base R's `factor`?

```
myFac <- factor(x, levels=x, labels=c("Apple", "Banana", "Missing", "x", "y", "z"))
myFac
[1] Apple   Banana  Missing x       y       z      
Levels: Apple Banana Missing x y z
```

If desired, you can convert this to a character vector:

```
as.character(myFac)
[1] "Apple"   "Banana"  "Missing" "x"       "y"       "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, I use `ifelse`. Your example would be: `x <- ifelse(x == "", "Missing", x)`.

In a `data.frame` context, you can use it inside `mutate`:

```
df_x <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "", "x", "y", "z"))
df_new <- df_x %>% 
          mutate(col1 = ifelse(col1 == "", "Missing", col1))
```