# Recode empty string with dplyr::recode

Tags: r, string, dplyr, na, recode

Consider these `factor` objects:

```
x <- factor(c(1,2,2,4,5), 1:5, labels = c('Ja', 'Nein', '', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort'))
y <- factor(c(1:5), 1:5, labels = c('Ja', 'Nein', '', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort'))

> table(x)
x
           Ja          Nein                  Weiß nicht Keine Antwort 
            1             2             0             1             1 

> table(y)
y
           Ja          Nein                  Weiß nicht Keine Antwort 
            1             1             1             1             1
```

I'm trying to use `dplyr::recode` to recode various variables. I can't get the function to recode an empty string level to `NA` and to drop the specific factor level.

Using

```
dplyr::recode(x,
              "Weiß nicht" = NA_character_,
              "Weiß nicht " = NA_character_,
              "Keine Antwort" = NA_character_,
              "Keine Antwort " = NA_character_,
              "k.A." = NA_character_,
              "Keine Angabe" = NA_character_,
              "0" = NA_character_,
              "" = NA_character_)
```

will result in an error message (`Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name`). Using

```
z <- dplyr::recode(na_if(x, ""),
              "Weiß nicht" = NA_character_,
              "Weiß nicht " = NA_character_,
              "Keine Antwort" = NA_character_,
              "Keine Antwort " = NA_character_,
              "k.A." = NA_character_,
              "Keine Angabe" = NA_character_,
              "0" = NA_character_)
```

as described in [Recode character vector with some empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936369/recode-character-vector-with-some-empty-strings) does not get rid of the empty string level:

```
> table(z)
z
  Ja Nein      
   1    2    0 
> levels(z)
[1] "Ja"   "Nein" ""
```

Additionally, I can't simply use `droplevels` because I want to use the function on variables which may have empty categories I need to retain.

A solution would need to provide to things:

1. Recode any occurence of `""` to `NA`.
2. Drop level `""` from `factor` variable, even when it is unused (as in `x`), without dropping **every** unused level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assign the `levels` that are `""` to `NA` before the `recode`

```
levels(x)[levels(x)==""] <- NA_character_
y <- dplyr::recode(x,
          "Weiß nicht" = NA_character_,
          "Weiß nicht " = NA_character_,
          "Keine Antwort" = NA_character_,
          "Keine Antwort " = NA_character_,
          "k.A." = NA_character_,
          "Keine Angabe" = NA_character_,
          "0" = NA_character_))

levels(y)
#[1] "Ja"   "Nein"

table(y)
y
#  Ja Nein 
#  23 2728
```

---

Using the smaller dataset

```
x2 <- x1[1:7]
levels(x2)[levels(x2)==""] <- NA_character_
x2
#[1] b    b    e    d    d    <NA> b   
#Levels: a b c d e


table(dplyr::recode(x2, "b" = NA_character_))

#  a c d e 
#  0 0 2 1
```

Here 'c' and 'a' are unused levels, while 'b' is changed to `NA` as well as `""` to `NA`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x1 <- factor(sample(c(letters[1:5], ""), 20, replace = TRUE))
x2 <- x1[1:7]
```

Comment: This will drop all unused levels, though, won't it? I need to retain unused levels that are not mentioned in the recoding scheme, otherwise I could just use `droplevels`.

Comment: @LAP Yes, that is right, but isn't this the problem

Comment: The problem is recoding any cases of `""` that occur in the data to `NA` and dropping this specific level from `factor` items, without dropping every unused level. I'll clarify it in my question.

Comment: @LAP Please make it a more general case.  You have a big example.  Make it short and general

Comment: @LAP I updated the post.  Please check if this is what yo uwanted

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution, thank you. It bugs me though that `recode` is unable to solve this.

Comment: Is there a solution that is able to differentiate between `NA_character_` and `""`?  (without recoding first)

Comment: I filed a feature request at dplyrs github, I don't know how fast they are with implementing things like this, and how likely they are to implement feature requests from random people at all, but I guess It's worth a try.

the feature request: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4628

Comment: @snaut The `""` is blank and not a missing value.  differentiation is with `is.na` as the `NA_character` returns TRUE with `is.na`

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of this, the problem is not that it is not possible to differentiate between `NA_character_` and `""` but, that one cannot use `""` as name for a named argument in the function `recode`.